# if(true), then document.write but doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>

    var now = new Date();
    document.write(now.getMinutes() + " " + now.getSeconds() + " "
            + now.getMilliseconds());

    if (now.getSeconds() == 0) {
        var time = now.getMilliSeconds();
        document.write("HELLO");
        document.write("<form action=\"Second\" method=\"GET\">");
        document.write("<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"temp\" id=\"a\" />");
        document.getElementById("a").value = time;
        document.write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" /> </form>");
    }
    else {
        window.location.reload("http://localhost:8080/firstweb/NewFile1.jsp");
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to write a js code that examines the millisecond whenever specified second is reached by refreshing. But appearantly, document.write() doesn't do anything. whenever it reaches 0 second, it just does

```
document.write(now.getMinutes() + " " + now.getSeconds() + " "
        + now.getMilliseconds());
```

this but not the ones inside if statement. How could I fix it?

p.s. is it possible, like, for example at 9:00 clock, make certain code run?

Comment: It only worked when your DOM is completely loaded or ready.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is in the head. The document may not exist when it is loaded (and run). Plus, you really don't need to reload the same document just to re-execute the script. This is going to cause a whole lot of requests for nothing. Try putting your script in a function, and calling it from a window.setTimeout().

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "The document may not exist when it is loaded". `document` is a variable that is created automatically. Plus `document.write` should only be used if the document hasn't finished loading. The part about not refreshing is true though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

var now = new Date();
document.write(now.getMinutes() + " " + now.getSeconds() + " "
        + now.getMilliseconds());

if (now.getSeconds() == 0) {
   var time = now.getMilliseconds();
    document.write("HELLO");
    document.write("<form action=\"Second\" method=\"GET\">");
    document.write("<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"temp\" id=\"a\" />");
    document.getElementById("a").value = time;
    document.write("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" /> </form>");

}
else {
    window.location.reload("http://localhost:8080/firstweb/NewFile1.jsp");
}
```

try it it works for me 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Incredible, it doesn't work cause this line of code:

```
    var time = now.getMilliSeconds();
```

the s of Seconds should be lower, so:

```
    var time = now.getMilliseconds();
```

it will works fine!